# C# Single Serial port data reading from multiple application simultaneously

Tags: c#

I have two application which is using single device port simultaneously. I want both application should access same port at time without closing and opening port.

Can we access same port ?

OR

Is device sending to particular data on particular serial port can switch to another port For e.g  Device 1 using Comport 1 and sending data on same Can Com1 data can redirect to Com2 ?

Comment: No. Who is going to do the reading? Who is going to send and when? What if both applications try to send data at the same time? Serial ports are a *simple* mechanism to connect two devices

Comment: Conceivably you could make some sort of splitter class that decodes messages streaming in and categorise them. Then have the other programs take in its input from the splitter *shrug* hard to know all the details of this problem

Comment: You can create *one* application/service that receives requests from the other applications and uses the port to send one request at a time. If multiple applications want to receive the same data, the service can publish the data it receives to them