# c# com port data shared to multiple application

Tags: c#

App1 - accessing com port and reading data from com port continuously.

App2 and App3  required same data which is read by App1 com port but App1 have continuous access of same com port so App2 and App3 can't access or get the data by same port.

so is there any way or solution to get the same com port data to App2 and App3 or to any other com port.

note : App2 and App3 didn't have access to App1. and com port always in access by App1.

Comment: [google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=windows+com+port+multiplexer&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: @user2033402 please tell me you are joking

Comment: Schoolwork? Because the exact same question was [asked less than 1 minute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111269/c-sharp-single-serial-port-data-reading-from-multiple-application-simultaneously) ago. Just google for this. You'll find the answer. SO is for answering specific programming questions. Make sure you know what you look for though - a multiplexer allows multiple applications to use a port, one at a time. Having multiple applications receive the same data is a different problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,  Thanks for attention and reply......